# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError when creating user

Tags: ruby, parameters, model, submit, ruby-on-rails-5

I’m using Rails 5 and Postgres 9.5.  I’m having a trouble when submitting a form meant to create an user in my database. I have this in my controller

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "You signed up successfully"
      flash[:color]= "valid"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
      flash[:color]= "invalid"
    end
    render "new"
  end
```

and here’s how my table looks in my Postgres database …

```
sims=> \d users;
                                         Table "public.users"
       Column       |            Type             |                     Modifiers                      
--------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id                 | integer                     | not null default nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
 username           | character varying           | 
 email              | character varying           | 
 encrypted_password | character varying           | 
 salt               | character varying           | 
 first_name         | character varying           | 
 last_name          | character varying           | 
 created_at         | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at         | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

But upon submitting my form with the below parameters, I get the error, as you can see from my logs …

```
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"q4YmPjUhD5olnRRgCt/gUuCDrb0lt+EqOxpzXGdtGHBtkwPEYgyp12H8lF04FHpqrZRZCip1Mo8/tvGQinPpJg==", "user"=>{"username"=>”mysuername”, "email"=>”mysuername@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Signup"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):
```

There is no other information in the logs.  What else do I need to do to get my form to submit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails is preventing the save because of security concerns.  This guide has a nice, concise explanation:  http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/rails-4-strong-paremeters

To fix your specific example, change the `@user = User.new(params[:user])` line to:

```
@user = User.new(params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation))
```